# Como obter usuário logado na view?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

Estou precisando obter o usuário que esta logado em minha aplicação, fiz o exemplo abaixo mas não funciona.

Na minha tag nav utilizei a importação  asp.net core e @inject

```
      <nav class="site-menu ">


        <ul>

            <li>
                <a href="shop-grid-ls.html"><span>Vendedores</span></a>

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="shop-grid-ls.html"><span>Clientes</span></a>

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="shop-grid-ls.html"><span>Produtos</span></a>

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="shop-grid-ls.html"><span>Vendas</span></a>

            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="shop-grid-ls.html"><span>Relatórios</span></a>

            </li>
        </ul>

        <div id="NomeUsuarioLogado"></div> <!-- Importação aspnetcore e httcontextaccessor-->
        @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
        @inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

    </nav>
```

O segundo passo é criar uma função JavaScript que pega o usuario logado.

```
<script>
    function CarregaUsuarioLogado() {

        var nome = '@HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("NomeUsuarioLogado")'



        if (nome != "") {

            var divNome = document.getElementById("NomeUsuarioLogado");
            divNome.innerHTML = "Olá " + nome;
            divNome.style = "color:#000000; padding-top: 15px;";

        } else {
            //window.location.href = '../Home/Login';
        }
    }
</script>
```

e por ultimo na minha tag

```
onload="CarregaUsuarioLogado()

<body onload="CarregaUsuarioLogado()">
```

Comment: Você está utilizando o Identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o Identity basta apenas fazer assim:

**Na View**

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager


//DIV onde vai aparecer o nome do usuário logado
<div>@UserManager.GetUserName(User)</div>


//OU

<div>@User.Identity.Name</div>
```